# make an IntentService not sleep until it executes a handler.postDelayed runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice, postdelayed

In the onHandleIntent of my my IntentService class, I created handle containing a runnable which should be done after 20 seconds. Unfortunatly my service sleeps or is destroyed before this period.
I tried also with the CountDownTimer, but i had the same problem.
Do someone have any idea can I make the onHnadleIntent waiting? Thank you!

This is the code:

```
 public class MyService extends IntentService {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("20 seconds later","I am here");
            }
        }, 20000);
        //...
   }
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an `IntentService`. It is not designed for your scenario. Use a regular `Service`. Put your code in `onStartCommand()`. At the bottom of your `run()` method, call `stopSelf()` on the `Service` instance to shut it down.

Comment: This is the same issue, is that correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949239/handler-postdelayed-is-not-working-in-onhandleintent-method-of-intentservice

Why exactly, would you know? Basically, my app is still in foreground and screen is still on, and still this doesn't work... creating a new HandlerThread for network tasks when IntentService is available sounds like overkill unless a solid reason be there. Pls...

Comment: @AA_PV: `HandlerThread` is *much* lighter-weight than is `IntentService`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop onHandleIntent from returning until the Runnable has completed. This can be achieved by using a CountdownLatch, which awaits at the end of your onHandleIntent method, and gets released at the end of the run method.

NOTE: this will cause the intent service to not process other Intents you sent it until the previous one has completed (after 20 seconds).

You may also want to obtain a partial wakelock at the start of onHandleIntent and release it at the end.

Comment: Thank you for response! I don't know if it would work for me or not, I didn't try it. I hope it helps another one.